# Creating dictionary from a csv file

Tags: python, csv, dictionary, nested

I have a csv file as shown below:

**EmpID**;**Day**;**Duty**
521;0;1
521;1;1
521;2;0
521;3;0
521;4;1
521;5;1
521;6;0
521;7;0
521;8;1
521;9;1
521;10;0
521;11;0
521;12;1
521;13;1
879;0;1
879;1;0
879;2;1
879;3;0
879;4;1
879;5;0
879;6;1
879;7;0
879;8;1
879;9;0
879;10;1
879;11;0
879;12;1
879;13;1
978;0;1
978;1;1
978;2;0
978;3;1
978;4;1
978;5;1
978;6;0
978;7;1
978;8;1
978;9;1
978;10;1
978;11;1
978;12;0
978;13;1
979;0;1
979;1;1
979;2;1
979;3;0
979;4;1
979;5;1
979;6;1
979;7;0
979;8;1
979;9;1
979;10;1
979;11;1
979;12;0
979;13;1\

The first number indicates the ID of an employee, then the number of the day of the work schedule and the last number indicates whether the employee is working that day.

0: the employee is **NOT** working that day
1: the employee **IS** working that day

I want to write a dictionary that has the **EmpID** as key and another dictionary as the value. The inner dictionary should contain the **Day** as key and the **Duty** as value.

So this is what I have:

```
def schedule_dict(file):

    the_dict = csv.DictReader(file, delimiter = ';')

    schedule={}

    for item in the_dict:

        schedule[item['EmpID']] = {}

        for thing in the_dict:
     
            schedule[item['EmpID']].update({thing['Day'] : thing['Duty']})

            if int(thing['Day']) == 13:
                break
    
    return schedule
```

I have read the csv file with the `DictReader` command and I get this dictionary:

```
{
    '521': {'1': '1', '2': '0', '3': '0', '4': '1', '5': '1', '6': '0', '7': '0', '8': '1', '9': '1', '10': '0', '11': '0', '12': '1', '13': '1'},
    '879': {'1': '0', '2': '1', '3': '0', '4': '1', '5': '0', '6': '1', '7': '0', '8': '1', '9': '0', '10': '1', '11': '0', '12': '1', '13': '1'},
    '978': {'1': '1', '2': '0', '3': '1', '4': '1', '5': '1', '6': '0', '7': '1', '8': '1', '9': '1', '10': '1', '11': '1', '12': '0', '13': '1'},
    '979': {'1': '1', '2': '1', '3': '0', '4': '1', '5': '1', '6': '1', '7': '0', '8': '1', '9': '1', '10': '1', '11': '1', '12': '0', '13': '1'}
}
```

But I still need the first day that is number as zero ('0').

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
with open("your_file.csv", "r") as f:
    the_dict = list(map(lambda y: y.split(";"), [line.strip() for line in f]))
schedule = {}
for item in the_dict:
    if item[0] not in schedule.keys():
        schedule.setdefault(item[0], {item[1]: item[2]})
    else:
        schedule[item[0]].update({item[1]: item[2]})
print(schedule)
```

```py
{
'521': {'0': '1', '1': '1', '2': '0', '3': '0', '4': '1', '5': '1', '6': '0', '7': '0', '8': '1', '9': '1', '10': '0', '11': '0', '12': '1', '13': '1'}
'879': {'0': '1', '1': '0', '2': '1', '3': '0', '4': '1', '5': '0', '6': '1', '7': '0', '8': '1', '9': '0', '10': '1', '11': '0', '12': '1', '13': '1'}
'978': {'0': '1', '1': '1', '2': '0', '3': '1', '4': '1', '5': '1', '6': '0', '7': '1', '8': '1', '9': '1', '10': '1', '11': '1', '12': '0', '13': '1'}
'979': {'0': '1', '1': '1', '2': '1', '3': '0', '4': '1', '5': '1', '6': '1', '7': '0', '8': '1', '9': '1', '10': '1', '11': '1', '12': '0', '13': '1'}
}
```

Comment: Just tested your solution. If the `int` indices are replaced with the column names (`0`->`'EmpID'`, `1`->`'Day'`, `2`->`'Duty'`), the solution works with the CSV reader.

Comment: updated to work with file.